7.5 * 2 results in 15., with a trailing dot. How can I get rid of it?
Using zsh:

width=7.25; echo $(( width * 2 )): the output is 14.5
width=7.5; echo $(( width * 2 )): the output is 15., with a trailing dot

This seems to be a very basic thing, but I haven't figured it out. How can I get just 15, without the trailing dot, in the second example?

Related: Why does $((0.1)) expand to 0.10000000000000001 in zsh?, where if you read it till the end, you'll likely find that you probably want to pass the result to printf '%g\n', or even use printf '%g\n' 'width * 2' here instead of echo to produce human-friendly output.

zsh is one of the 3 Bourne-like shells (with ksh93 and yash) that support both integer arithmetic and floating point arithmetic in there arithmetic expressions (inside (( ... )), $(( ... )), ${array[...]} and most builtins that take numbers as arguments like in ksh where those features come from).
Those arithmetic expressions are shaped after the C language and follow mostly the same rules¹. In particular, an operation that involves only integers yields an integer. And as soon as a float is involved, there's a promotion to float.
Like in C, a numeric literal is considered as floating point if it contains a . or uses the engineering notation (1e-2...) or is one of the variants of NaN or Infinity² and integer otherwise, so appending a . to a sequence of decimal digits is the easiest way to make sure it's taken as a float constant rather than integer constance.
For example, in C like in zsh / ksh93³ / yash, 2 / 4 * 6. yields 0. because 2 / 4 yields the 0 integer, and 0 * 6. yields the 0. float.
While 2. / 4 * 6 yields 3. because 2. / 4 is a floating point operation because at least one of the operands is a float which yields 0.5 and 0.5 * 6 is also a float operation.
$ print -rl  '#include <stdio.h>' 'int main() {printf("%.17g\n", 2 / 4 * 6.);}' | tcc -run -
0
$ print -rl  '#include <stdio.h>' 'int main() {printf("%.17g\n", 2. / 4 * 6);}' | tcc -run -
3

Same in ksh93:
$ print "$(( 2 / 4 * 6. ))"
0
$ print "$(( 6. * 2 / 4 ))"
3

Or zsh:
$ print $(( 2 / 4 * 6. ))
0.
$ print $(( 6. * 2 / 4 ))
3.

Except that zsh preserves the information that the expression yielded a float by adding that .. It doesn't add that . if the number is already a floating representation for other reasons such as:
$ print $(( 1./0 )) $(( 0./0 )) $(( 10. ** 20 ))
Inf NaN 1e+20

More generally, when zsh gives you a decimal text representation of a floating pointing point number (which it stores internally as the double C type), it tries to give you a completely faithful representation, so that if that is used later in another arithmetic expression, there is no loss of information happening, including both on type (integer vs float) and precision.
That's why besides adding that . to disambiguate float from integers, it uses the %.17g sprintf() format when computing the decimal integer text representation of the number, as 17 digits is the minimum number of decimal digits needed in the general case to make sure the full precision of a 64bit IEEE 754 double precision binary number is retained. And that much precision has the disadvantage of exposing the errors incurred by conversion between decimal and binary.
That's discussed at length at Why does $((0.1)) expand to 0.10000000000000001 in zsh?
Now, for human consumption, you generally don't need to see that . to know it's meant to be a floating point number, not that you'd care if it's meant to be or not. And you don't need to see that much precision, so for display purposes and for human consumption only, best it to use printf or print -f to format the number.
printf '%g\n' width
print -f '%g\n' width

Would print the value of width formatted the same way as awk for instance would format it with 6 digits of precision (also switching to 9.9999e-05 or 1e06 for numbers under 1e-4 or above 1e6)
$ printf '%1$25s: %1$g\n' 0.1 0.1000001 $((0.1)) 1000000 '1e-4 - 1e-9' $(( 1e-4  -1e-9 ))
                      0.1: 0.1
                0.1000001: 0.1
      0.10000000000000001: 0.1
                  1000000: 1e+06
              1e-4 - 1e-9: 9.9999e-05
   9.9999000000000003e-05: 9.9999e-05

$ awk 'BEGIN {print 0.1, 0.10000001, 1000000, 1000000.1, 1e-4 - 1e-9}'
0.1 0.1 1000000 1e+06 9.9999e-05

Here with the difference that numbers don't go through OFMT format if they are deemed to be integers.
Use:
printf '%.17g\n' width

If you want to preserve as much precision as possible while still removing the . for those numbers that don't have a decimal part.
Like in ksh, it's also possible to declare a variable with:
typeset -F2 x
typeset -E6 y

For $x to be expressed with floating point notation with 2 digits after the period when expanded (as with the %.2f printf directive) and $y to be expressed in engineering notation with 6 significant digits (as with %.6e printf directive), but I don't think there's an equivalent for %g.
Note that the value of the variable is still stored internally with full precision, those -F/-E attributes only affect the expansions.
$ typeset -F2 x
$ typeset -E6 y
$ x=0.123456789
$ echo $x
0.12
$ echo $((x))
0.123456789
$ y=x
$ echo $y
1.23457e-01


¹ Except zsh contrary to ksh has some incompatibilities when it comes to operator precedence, though that's not relevant to this question.
² Note that contrary to ksh93 or yash or C99, it doesn't support floating point hexadecimals such as 0xDead.Beef or 0x123p-4 yet though.
³ Though beware that ksh93 honours the locale's decimal radix character; in a locale where it's , instead of ., that would have to be written 2 / 4 * 6,

Thanks a lot, Stéphane. My understanding of math and shells is not really strong. Could you explain, how the use of printf is different from the parameter expansion suggested by Gilles, conceptually? That is, is it a more correct way, and why?

${...%.} removes a trailing ., printf '%g\n' does that and reduces the precision of the number so it's easier to read for a human. For a non-human, that is, if the output number is  to be reused for further calculation, it's probably better to keep as much precision as possible, and keeping the . won't harm and also keep the information that the number is meant to be a floating point.

To just get rid of the trailing dot, use the ${name%pattern} form of parameter expansion.
echo ${$(( width * 2 ))%.}

This won't help you if the result isn't an integer due to approximations.
echo $(((0.1 + 0.2) * 10))
3.0000000000000004

If you don't like that result:

Read what every programmer should know about floating-point arithmetic
If you still want to use floating point and you still don't like that result, go to 1.


echo ${$(( width * 2 ))%.} works fine for me: 7.5 x 2 = 15, 7.25 x 2 = 14.5, like in elementary school. Thanks.

This is somewhat weird to me that the trailing dot is not removed by default, that is, if using just echo $(( width * 2 )).

@jsx97 Why would the trailing dot be removed? 7.5 * 2 is the floating point number 15. whereas 15 is an integer.

Ah, now I see, thanks. I assumed floating point will be automatically converted to integer, which is not what most of the programming languages will do automatically.

@jsx97, There's an int() arithmetic function to convert to integer in the zsh/mathfunc module, or if you want to produce an output for human consumption, just pass the number to printf '%g\n', which is short for printf '%.6g\n' which drops the precision from 17 (as much as is needed to represents those double faithfully) to 6 digits, removing most artefacts caused by binary floating point arithmetics. That's the same in awk where the default OFMT and CONVFMT are %.6g.
